# Date_range between 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-manipulation

Im kinda new to Python and Datascience.

I have a Dataset with 2 datetime columns `A` and `B` :

```
                     A                    B
0  2019-03-13 08:12:20  2019-03-13 08:12:25
1  2019-03-15 10:02:18  2019-03-13 10:02:20
```

For each row, i want to generate the date range in seconds between column A and column B, so as a result i should get this :

```
                    A
0 2019-03-13 08:12:20
1 2019-03-13 08:12:21
2 2019-03-13 08:12:22
3 2019-03-13 08:12:23
4 2019-03-13 08:12:24
5 2019-03-13 08:12:25
```

I made it work with this :

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame({'A': ["2019-03-13 08:12:20", "2019-03-15 10:02:18"], 'B': ["2019-03-13 08:12:25", "2019-03-13 10:02:20"]})
l=[pd.date_range(start=df.iloc[i]['A'], end=df.iloc[i]['B'], freq='S') for i in range(len(df))]
df1=(pd.DataFrame(l).T)[0]
print(df1)
```

But as i have like 1M rows, it's taking too much time to run and i know that this solution isn't really the best, can you please guys show me whats the best way to do this ?

Comment: `df.apply(lambda row : list(pd.date_range(row['A'], end=row['B'], freq='S')), axis=1).explode()`

Comment: I have a Dataset with like 1M rows, i don't think that apply will do the job x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is necessary loop, one possible solution with list comprehension and flattening:

```
l = [x for a, b in zip(df.A, df.B) for x in pd.date_range(a, b, freq='S')]
df1= pd.DataFrame({'A':l})
print(df1)
                    A
0 2019-03-13 08:12:20
1 2019-03-13 08:12:21
2 2019-03-13 08:12:22
3 2019-03-13 08:12:23
4 2019-03-13 08:12:24
5 2019-03-13 08:12:25
```

Another solution:

```
df1 = (pd.concat([pd.Series(pd.date_range(r.A, r.B, freq='S')) for r in df.itertuples()])
         .to_frame('A'))
print (df1)
                    A
0 2019-03-13 08:12:20
1 2019-03-13 08:12:21
2 2019-03-13 08:12:22
3 2019-03-13 08:12:23
4 2019-03-13 08:12:24
5 2019-03-13 08:12:25
```

Comment: Is there another way to achieve this without a loop?

Comment: ya, `apply`are still loops under the hood, so not useable, maybe exist some beetr solution in numpy.

Comment: Can you direct me to the right way to do this with numpy ?